# Smarty: Combine variable with attribute

Tags: concatenation, smarty, attr

How do i add the value of a variable in the middle of an attribute in smarty?

Example:

```
{for $limit=1 to 50}
   {if {$customer_data.attribute.kind{$limit}aktiv} == '1'} // I want to place the $limit variable right behind 'kind'
       "Activ!"
   {/if}
{/for}
```

Answer (score 0):

For clarity, you can compute the attribute name on a separate line. You can accomplish the concatenation using [backticks](https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.syntax.quotes.tpl).

```
{for $limit=1 to 5}
  {assign "attrName" "kind`$limit`aktiv"}
  {if $customer_data.attribute.$attrName == '1'}
    <div>{$attrName} Activ!</div>
  {/if}
{/for}
```

PHP sample data:

```php
$smarty->assign('customer_data', [
  'attribute' => [
    'kind1aktiv' => 0,
    'kind2aktiv' => 1,
    'kind3aktiv' => 1,
    'kind4aktiv' => 0,
    'kind5aktiv' => 1,
  ],
]);
```

As a closing thought, you could consider preparing a simpler data structure in PHP. Smarty shouldn't have to concern itself with calculations, only presentation.